# Axis2 HTTP 400 error with VS2010 development server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, http, apache-axis

I have a simple problem that I can't currently recreate and I need to solve next Monday.

In a development environment, we have a .NET4 service running on ASP.NET test server provided by VS2010 and a Java client running Axis2. We found that all requests fail. With Wireshark we found a `400 Bad request` error on every request.

We found that each request from Java client required `transfer-encoding: chunked`. The rest seemed well formed. After the headers and a few bytes the server throws 400 error.

Questions are:

#### Does .NET test server support chunked transfers?

#### How can I tell Axis2 to use plain HTTP without even keep-alive just to be sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer 1

No, it doesn't. Disabling chunked encoding makes everything work!

### Answer 2

http://wso2.org/library/209 provides information about how to disable chunked transfers (with an error in their code)

```
FooStub stub = new FooStub(); 
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
```